# Google Visualization Animation when chart loads for the first time

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I would like to know if I can apply an animation to the charts on the first time it draws?

And not only when a change of data happens?

THanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Chart should be rendered before you can apply your animation which is showing **transition** from one state to another. You can either change the **data** or change the **chart options** to create the transition and its animation.

To be able to show animation on *the first time*, you can simply create an empty (no data) chart, and then add your data to the chart, to show the data animation.

```
var options = {
  animation:{
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'out',
  }
};
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'N');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart...
chart.draw(data, options);
// Adding data
data.addRow(['V', 200]);
```

Comment: BTW, how can I load empty data table?

Comment: Thanks Guy. I'm planning to use this for ChartWrapper method by getting data from MySQL as JSON.Is that possible?

Comment: You need to write the conversion between the JSON format of your query and the one of DataTable. But it is certainly possible.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, do you have to redraw after you add the data?

Comment: No. It should be automatic. Check that you added the values in the correct format (String, number...).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? Got a working jsFiddle or anything similar?

Comment: Didn't work for me either (API V3). And it makes sense: why changing the data would update the chart automatically? In Java you would need to update the adapter.

Comment: worked for me after I used startup: true along with this.

Answer (score 17):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Google has updated chart options and added the option to animate the chart on the first time it draws.

So the only thing you have to do is psecify it in the options like that:

```
var options = {
            animation: {
                duration: 1500,
                startup: true //This is the new option
            }
        };
```

So you dont have to load an empty chart on the beggining or to do any other hack.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gb758owr/)

Comment: This answer won't work for Gauge charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge  "the animation.startup option available for many other Google Charts is not available for the Gauge Chart. If you'd like a startup animation, draw the chart initially with values set to zero, and then draw again with the value you'd like it to animate to."

Comment: @BRass That's true. For the Gauge Chart, you have to use one of the other answers. But for most (if not all) of the Google charts gallery, this answers works just fine

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/h7mSQ/163/. The way to do this is to render chart with zero values and then set values as required and draw chart again. Don't forget to set minimal and maximal value for (in this example) vertical axis.

```
function drawChart() {
  var option = {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption in our company",
               width:600, height:400,
               animation: {duration: 1000, easing: 'out',},
               vAxis: {title: "Cups of coffee", minValue:0, maxValue:500},
               hAxis: {title: "Year"}};
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();    
  data.addColumn('string', 'N');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addRow(['2003', 0]);
  data.addRow(['2004', 0]);
  data.addRow(['2005', 0]);
  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, option);
  data.setValue(0, 1, 400);
  data.setValue(1, 1, 300);
  data.setValue(2, 1, 400);
  chart.draw(data, option);

}

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```